# Is there an easy way to keep iPhoto '09 from importing JPEGs that are duplicates of RAW photos?

Tags: jpeg, import, iphoto, automator, camera-raw

I know, I should just bite the bullet and use Aperture.  But short of that, when I connect my Canon G10 to my computer, iPhoto helpfully offers to import all my photos...which include the RAW files I really want and the JPEG previews that are created by the camera automatically, so I get two of each photo.  There is no way to shoot RAW only on the camera that I am aware of, but that would be a solution of sorts.  I think the camera display only shows the JPEGs on the screen for the preview function...that would be something to test.

Automator would be a possible option, I guess.  I will have to look at what iPhoto commands it offers.  If anyone's done this with Automator, I'd love to hear your solution.

But even Automator is a solution after the fact...what I really want to do is not import the JPEGs, not import them and turn around and delete them.  It offends my sense of hackerly elegance, I guess.  But I'll settle for not having to do it by hand. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It sounds like](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/CanonG10/page4.asp) you can shoot in either RAW mode or RAW+Jpeg mode.

Comment: Argh.  Now you know why I'm a network administrator, not a photographer.  Thank you.  That certainly works.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to keep shooting in RAW+JPG mode, I've made a little AppleScript to make it easier to find those dupes in order to, for instance, delete them:
[iPhoto non-RAW keyword tagging](http://www.tempel.org/IPhotoNonRAW)